# How to create a variable using Color class which includes only selected colors?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a variable using Color class which includes only selected colors but I don't know how or is it even possible to do it?

Comment: ***which includes only selected colors*** what do you mean, where are those colors???

Comment: [Java: Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Like a Set<Color>?

Comment: Or `EnumSet<Color>`.

Comment: Yes but it have to include colors:blue,red,white so i can add them in a variable and use this variable in a code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a color palette (containing the predefined colors) as **enum**:

```
public enum ColorPalette {
    BLUE(new Color(0x3388c1)),
    GREEN(new Color(0x96be0a)),
    YELLOW(new Color(0xffc901)),
    ORANGE(new Color(0xf79803)),
    RED(new Color(0xd74943));

    private final Color color;

    private ColorPalette(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

To use these colors in varaibles, and extract the `Color` when needed:

```
ColorPalette blue=ColorPalette.BLUE;
Color color = blue.getColor();
```

That way, you can also

- list the colors (`ColorPalette.values()`)
- get the name of each color (`somecolor.name()`)
- get the color by name (`ColorPalette.valueOf("GREEN")`) (attention: case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Color[] color = new Color[3];
color[0] = Color.red;
color[1] = Color.black;
color[2] = Color.white;
```

or try this

```
List<Color> colors = new ArrayList();
colors.add(Color.red);
colors.add(Color.black);
colors.add(Color.white);
```